Group actions confusion
I have been using results from this paper in calculations. In sections 2.4 and 3.4 they perform a canonical transformation into new coordinates consisting of constants of motion. They then construct an SL$(2, \mathbb{R})$ algebra that acts on these coordinates.
The canonical transformation for Schwarzschild $(r, \phi, p_r, p_\phi) \rightarrow (T, \Phi, H, L)$ is given by
\begin{align}
    d T &= \frac{Hr^4}{\left(r^2-2Mr\right)\sqrt{\mathcal{R}(r)}}d r \\
    d \Phi &= d\phi -  \frac{L}{\sqrt{\mathcal{R}(r)}} d r.
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}\label{eq:HamSchw}
    H = \sqrt{\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\left(\frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2}+ \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)p_r^2\right).}
\end{equation}
We can then define a generator
\begin{equation}
H_0 = (H- \tilde{H}(L)) T
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{H}(L)$ is the Hamiltonian of the null bound geodesics
\begin{equation}
\tilde{H}(L) = |L|/ \sqrt{27M^2}.
\end{equation}
Now the number of orbits for an unbound geodesic can be calculated through the winding number $w = \Delta \phi /(2\pi)$. It can be shown that $\Delta \phi$ in the limit of bound null geodesics is given by $$\Delta \phi = \ln(R_{\text{min}}^{-2})$$ where $R$ is defined through $r = 3M(1+R)$. In this case $$\{w, H_0\} = 1/(2\pi).$$
In section 2.4 the authors claim that the group action on the observable $w$ increases it to $w+1$ (see eq. (2.71)). I am confused on how this group action is defined, as I am not used to their conventions. How is the group action here defined in terms of Poisson brackets?

Please show the relevant sections of the paper so we don’t have to do a research project just to read your question.

@MattHanson I made an update :)

This should be familiar to you from the first example of generators of transformations we usually encounter: The bracket between position $q$ and momentum $p$ is constant as $\{q,p\} = 1$, and momentum generates translations $q\mapsto q + c, c\in \mathbb{R}$ as the corresponding one-parameter group action.
You have a constant Poisson bracket $\{w,H_0\}$, hence $H_0$ likewise generates translations $w\mapsto w+ c$ in $w$ as the corresponding group.
Both of these are special cases of the general idea that for any phase space function $f$, the group action generated by it on any other phase space function $g$ is simply given by $\partial_\phi (g\circ\exp(\phi f)) = \{g, f\}$ where $\exp(\phi f), \phi \in \mathbb{R}$ is the flow of the Hamiltonian vector field of $f$. See also this answer of mine.

But then I do not see how the group action leads to $w \rightarrow w+1$ if the group action is simply the Poisson bracket... I'm probably misunderstanding though

@Geigercounter The group action is not the Poisson bracket, the Poisson bracket is the infinitesimal version of the group action. The group action has a parameter $\phi$ so that $w(\phi)$ is what it does to $w$, and $\partial_\phi w(\phi) = {w,H_0}$ (this is more or less the definition of the flow/group action). The solution to the differential equation $\partial_\phi w(\phi) = 1$ with initial condition $w(0) = w$ is $w(\phi) = w + \phi$.

Yes but what is the particular formula to compute this? In some references I have found for example $$
e^{-\xi A}B e^{\xi A} \equiv \sum_n \frac{(-\xi)^n}{n!}\text{ad}^n_A B, \qquad \text{ad}_A B \equiv -{A,B}$$ for the group action of $A$ on $B$

@Geigercounter That's for linear operators on a vector space. In this case you have a phase space (which does not necessarily have a vector space  structure) and you compute the flow of the vector field by solving - as I already said - the differential equation $\partial_\phi w = { w, H_0 }$ with initial condition $w(0) = w$. Note that solving the equations of motion $\partial_t f = {f, H}$ for $H$ the Hamiltonian is just a special case of it and you don't have any "particular formula" to solve arbitrary equations of motion either, do you?

I think I am getting more confused. You said above that the group action is not the Poisson bracket, yet here you say that the group action is give by $\partial_\phi w = {w, H_0}$ (with an initial condition)? Are you simply saying that the group action is the same as the action of the generator and solving this equation? I then don't see how this constrains the constant shift of $w \rightarrow w+c$ to   $w \rightarrow w+1$

Moreover, what is then the $D_0$ group element introduced in (2.70)? Where does this come into play if we're simply solving the equations in my previous comment?
